# No slowdown when two sprites collide? Swift/Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I send one sprite off with an impulse touch, and another off with an impulse touch and they hit eachother, how do I allow them to keep their same speed instead of speeding up/slowing down from the contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `restitution` of each node's `physicsBody` to zero. From the [`SKPhysicsBody`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/restitution) documentation on `resitution`:

> This property is used to determine how much energy the physics body
>   loses when it bounces off another object. The property must be a value
>   between 0.0 and 1.0. The default value is 0.2.

Comment: Whoops, thought I had tried that before. This worked. Thanks a lot!